# How to change the color of custom icons in an action sheet ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to change the color of the custom icons (generated with IcoMoon) embedded in the following Action Sheet. I am working with Ionic Framework Version: 3.1.1

[image]

This is how look the three files related with the view:

**groups.html**

```
.
.
.
<ion-card>

    <img src="../../assets/img/groups/acoustics group.jpg"/>

    <ion-card-content>
        <ion-card-title>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col class="settitle">
                    Acoustics
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col class="rightcol">
                    <button class="iconmore" ion-button clear icon-only small (click)="openMenuGroup()" round>
                        <ion-icon name="more" ></ion-icon>
                    </button>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-card-title>
        <p class="content">
            22 Bookings <br>
            Since December 23th 2016
        </p>
    </ion-card-content>

</ion-card>
.
.
.
```

**groups.ts**

```
.
.
.
openMenuGroup() {
    let actionSheet = this.actionsheetCtrl.create({
        title: 'More',
        cssClass: 'action-sheets-groups-page',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'Edit',
                icon: 'icon-edition',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Edit clicked');
                }
            },
            {
                text: 'Delete',
                role: 'destructive',
                icon: 'icon-erase',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Delete clicked');
                }
            },              
            {
                text: 'Cancel',
                role: 'cancel', // will always sort to be on the bottom
                icon: 'close',
                handler: () => {
                    console.log('Cancel clicked');
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    actionSheet.present();
}
.
.
.
```

**groups.css**

```
page-groups {

    ion-content{

        .settitle{
            font-size: 70%;
            color: grey;
        }

        button.iconmore{
            font-size: 80%;
            color: grey;
        }

        ion-col.rightcol{
            direction: rtl;
        }

        p.content{
            font-size: 90%;
            color: grey;
        }
    }

    .action-sheets-groups-page {


        .icon-edition {
            color: grey;
        }
        .icon-erase {
            color: grey;
        }
        .action-sheet-cancel ion-icon,
        .action-sheet-destructive {
            color: grey;
        }
    }

}
```

thanks in advance!! I tried to follow the documentation but I couldn't how to do that.

Comment: replace `grey` with some other color?

Comment: I tried with all of the colors defined in `variables.scss`  file but doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

The key is set the styles in `global.scss`, because this action sheet is loading from out of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add styles in app.scss:

app.scss:

```
.ion-logo-whatsapp:before {
   color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## **Ionic 4 Solution Action Sheet Button Text Color Change**

1. You Have to add CSS-class to button like below example in your example.page.ts

   ```
   buttons: [{
       text: "Price : High to Low",
       icon: "arrow-round-up",
       cssClass: "dark", // css name can be anything
       handler: () => {
           this.getSortProducts("High to Low");
       }
   }]
   ```
2. Put your CSS into global.scss

   ```
   .dark {
     color: black !important;
   }
   ```

It is working only on from global.scss because this action sheet is loading from out of the page.

Thank You

Comment: PAY ATTENTION TO STEP 2.  It doesn't go in the component styles it goes in global.scss.

If I would have finished reading I would have saved myself 20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating this class in ionic.css

```
.action-sheet-has-icons .icon {
color:/*whatever you want*/
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. I put

`.action-sheet-has-icons .icon{
color: rgba(29,29,29,0.47);
}` 

because it didn't exist in ionic.css, however, without effect.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. Try following this article it will definitely help you https://www.tutorialsplane.com/ionic-2-action-sheet/. Just add the cssClass with each button

Comment: @Giannkas If nothing works try adding this class .action-sheet-button .action-sheet-icon{ color: rgba(29,29,29,0.47) !important; }

Comment: I follow the well specified instructions in the article but it doesn't work and the other option, in which file should I add these classes? in **ionic.css**? or in **groups.css**?

Comment: Try updating in both. Or in your custom style sheet or sass file

Answer (score 0):

```
.ion-logo-whatsapp:before {
    color: green;
}
.ion-md-share:before {
    color: color($colors,favorite);
}
.ion-md-close:before {
    color: red;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jPxz.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your scss file, you must move ".action-sheets-groups-page" class out of page-groups{} because your action sheet is not in your page
You should have instead

**groups.scss**

```
page-groups {
    ion-content{
        .settitle{
            font-size: 70%;
            color: grey;
        }
        button.iconmore{
            font-size: 80%;
            color: grey;
        }
        ion-col.rightcol{
            direction: rtl;
        }
        p.content{
            font-size: 90%;
            color: grey;
        }
    }

}

.action-sheets-groups-page {
    .icon-edition {
        color: grey;
    }
    .icon-erase {
        color: grey;
    }
    .action-sheet-cancel ion-icon,
    .action-sheet-destructive {
        color: grey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// in component ts      
  async presentActionSheet(body) {
            const actionSheet = await this.actionSheetController.create({
              header: "Options",
              buttons: [
                {
                  text: "Add More Item",
                  icon: "add",
                  cssClass: 'example', // <- add css class here only
                  handler: () => {
                    this.OpenTopupModal(body);
                  },
                },
                {
                  text: "Update Use Item",
                  icon: "pencil",
                  cssClass: 'example', // <- add css class here only
                  handler: () => {
                    this.openUsedItemModal(body);
                  },
                },
        ...
    
    
    in global.scss
    
    .example .action-sheet-icon {
      color: #1e3d6e !important;
    }
```